# Is there anything wrong with my "sum of list" code in scheme?

Tags: scheme

My else statement line is giving me an error. Is any of my other line of codes affecting the else expression?

```
(define (sumAdd list)
  (cond
    ((null? list) '())
    ((null? (cdr list)) list)
    ((symbol? list) sumAdd(cdr list))
    (else (+ (car list)(sumAdd (cdr list))))
    )
  )
```

Comment: what is `sumAdd(cdr list)`? not enough parentheses? :)

Comment: So when `(symbol? list)` you should check the value of the variable `sumAdd` and then throw that away to return `(cdr list)`? What is this supposed to return? I see it  returns a empty list, a list , the `cdr` of a symbol (what is that?) and of course the recursive case expects all those things to be working as numbers one can `+` with the first value. In fact the `else` is perhaps the only term that works.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to sum all the numbers in a list with mixed element types. If that's the case, there are several errors in your code:

```
(define (sumAdd list)                 ; `list` clashes with built-in procedure
  (cond
    ((null? list) '())                ; base case must be zero for addition
    ((null? (cdr list)) list)         ; why discard the last element?
    ((symbol? list) sumAdd(cdr list)) ; that's not how procedures are called
    (else (+ (car list) (sumAdd (cdr list)))))) ; this line is fine :)
```

This is the correct way to implement the procedure:

```
(define (sumAdd lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) 0)                           ; base case is zero
    ((symbol? (car lst)) (sumAdd (cdr lst)))  ; skip current element
    (else (+ (car lst) (sumAdd (cdr lst)))))) ; add current element
```

It works as expected:

```
(sumAdd '(1 a 2 b 3 c))
=> 6
```